# spatie/laravel-permission There is no permission named `edit_project` for guard `api`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel 5.6 with spatie/laravel-permission version 2.9 also using Laravel Passport as auth driver with `$guard = 'api'`.

When I am trying to assign an array of permission like `['edit_project', 'add_project' 'delete_project']` to a role with help of this function

```
public function assignPermissions($role, $permissions)
    {

        $role = Role::findByName($role);

        $role->givePermissionTo($permissions);

        return $role;
    }
```

but getting the error `There is no permission named`edit_project`for guard`api`.

Also I have at config/auth.php

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

if there is any solution please help me with it thanks.

as well I am seeding the permission table by help of Larvel seeder which my permission table looks at the first time like below which the `guard_name` is web.

[image]

but manually I am changing the `guard_name` field to "api" which my permission table became like this.

[image]

Comment: What does your `permissions` table look like?

Comment: @joelrosenthal I have edited the question please chick included images of my permissions table thanks.

Comment: @Barakzai Did this issue solve now? I am stuck in the same place now. Which of these solutions worked for you?

Answer (score 60):

After creating permissions, running the following commands should work as it worked for me.

```bash
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache
```

then

```bash
php artisan cache:clear
```

> Note: In `Ubuntu` you may need to run these commands as `sudo`...

Comment: this does not fix the issue for me, i still get the:
There is no permission named `menu_access` for guard `web`.

Answer (score 9):

Clear your cache `php artisan cache:clear`

if this does not work use `sudo php artisan cache:clear` it worked for me once i use sudo

Comment: this doesnt work, still get the:
There is no permission named `menu_access` for guard `web`.

Answer (score 6):

The package uses the default guard unless instructed otherwise. The way to instruct it otherwise is to add the following to the `Role` class `public $guard_name = 'api';`. Of course adding that to the class in the `vendor` directory is a bad idea so you'd want to extend it and specify the guard like this

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as OriginalRole;

class Role extends OriginalRole
{
    public $guard_name = 'api';
}
```

Then if you haven't done so already, generate the config file with `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

Lastly you'll want to register your `Role` in `config/permissions.php` by changing `'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,` to `'role' => \App\Models\Role::class,` (of course this will vary based on where your `Role` class is)

Also the example from your question mentions `add_project` but the database shows `create_project` so make sure you're using the same names everywhere.

Comment: if it doesn't work, try     public $guard_name = 'web';

Answer (score 4):

Move the web and api places from

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

To

```
'guards' => [

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ]
```

run `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Not quite, changing the order of the guards won't fix the problem. What could be done, although I would recommend against it is to change the default guard but that's set in the `defaults` in `config/auth.php`. If the default is being relied on anywhere in the application there would be side effects.

Comment: In my case the driver i was using under API guard was 'token' , so I changed my /config/auth.php to looks like this 
`
'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],        
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],        
    ],
`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the guard when creating a role or permission failure of which spatie will take on the first guard that appears in the config/auth in this case "web"

```
'defaults' => [
'guard' => 'web',
'passwords' => 'users',
   ],
```

You need to approach as follows:

```
// Create a manager role for users authenticating with the api guard:
$role = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'api', 'name' => 'manager']);

// Define a `edit_project` permission for the admin users belonging to the api guard
$permission = Permission::create(['guard_name' => 'api', 'name' => 'edit_project']);
```

Comment: I was facing issues for different guard then I check this work for me permission was not set to new guard so if there will be no permission to this error will occur .. This work for me

Answer (score 2):

It might be a permissions issue. run below command.

```
sudo php artisan permission:cache-reset
```

Answer (score 1):

In your user model add `protected $guard_name = 'api';` This will override the default guard which is **web**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from your code you can clear the cache straight from your code.

```php
\DB::table('permissions')->insert([['name' => 'create Stuff', 'guard_name' => 'web']]);
\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
$role = Role::findByName('admin');
$role->givePermissionTo('create Stuff');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another important aspect in this context (which was hitting me):

If you are using the `Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents` trait for your seeder and want to seed the Roles directly after seeding the Permissions, you will have to add the `forgetCachedPermissions()` before the Permissions are assigned to the Roles. Otherwise, the seeder throws an error, because it does not find the Permissions.

```php
// Seed permissions
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    Permission::create(['name' => $permission['name']]);
}

// IMPORTANT!
app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();

// Seed roles
foreach($roles as $role) {
    Role::create(['name' =>
        $role['name']])->givePermissionTo($role['permissions']);
}

app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the id field to an integer before calling the `syncPermissions` method:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($permissions as $key => $item){
   $data[$key] = (int)$item;
}

if (!empty($data)){
   $role->syncPermissions($data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it happens if you override model events; such as create, created, and updated, ...
I experienced this problem in my test cases when I used the `Event::fake()` to mock Events.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34125697)

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of research, I had to delete cache data manually. Laravel stores it on /storage/framework/cache/data. After that the new permission worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

So i was able to fix this;

convert the id field for integer before calling the syncPermissions method

$data = array();
`foreach ($permissions as $key => $item){$data[$key] = (int)$item;}`

if (!empty($data)){$role->syncPermissions($data);}

Comment: Please format your answer properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution. We should cast the item into as an integer.

```
$permissions = $request->input('permission');

$permissions = array_map(function ($item) {
  return (int)$item;
}, $permissions);
   
if (!empty($permissions)){
  $role->syncPermissions($permissions);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no permission named `1` for guard `web

can use :

use this  composer require spatie/laravel-permission "^5.11"    your problem will be solve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).