# spatie permission There is no permission named `create` for guard `web`. laravel

Tags: laravel, permissions

i am using spatie permissions but it returns an error

```
There is no permission named `create` for guard `web`.
```

i don't know why please help
my code what am i doing is i create a new user then i create permissions then i make the user instructor have the permissions i create, all of that is in the seeder

here is my code seeder

```
public function run()
{

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'instructor@gmail.com',
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => 'password', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        'type' =>  User::TYPE_INSTRUCTOR,
    ]);

    $permissions = 
    [
    [
        'name' => 'methods_create',
        'display_name' => 'create',
        'key' => 'methods',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'methods_update',
        'display_name' => 'update',
        'key' => 'methods',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'methods_delete',
        'display_name' => 'delete',
        'key' => 'methods',
    ],
    ];

    

    $role = Role::create(['name'=>'Instructor']);
    foreach($permissions as $permission){
        Permission::create($permission);
    }
    $role->givePermissionTo($permissions);
    $user->assignRole($role);
}
```

Comment: After running seeder you have to forgot and clear cache.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284199/19493852

Comment: the seeding returns an error after forget and clear cache
 There is no permission named `create` for guard `web`