# Laravel - Spatie Roles There is no permission named `ABR` for guard `web`

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

Following error has occured while I try to check permissions in Event after login and add some to User if he does not have assigned:

> Spatie
>  \ 
> Permission
>  \ 
> Exceptions
>  \ 
> PermissionDoesNotExist
> There is no permission named `ABR` for guard `web`.

What's so funnier, I've tried already to follow this post:

[spatie/laravel-permission There is no permission named edit_project for guard api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086974/spatie-laravel-permission-there-is-no-permission-named-edit-project-for-guard/53284199#53284199)

But the cache clearing direct for Spatie : `php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache` and then for whole app: `php artisan cache:clear` did not help.

What I wanted to do is to handle event after User login, that assigns the permission to his model.
Short demo:

```
     /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->givePermissionTo('ABR'); 
    }
```

My permissions are loaded through `*.txt` file, and then added to DB like `Permission::create(['name'=>'ABR']);` and so on.

Any idea how to fix this? `guard_name` is automatically assigned to `web`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `api` guard, it's as simple as:

```php
Permission::create(['name'=>'ABR', 'guard_name' => 'api']);
```